# pyenv unable to install python2.7.7 - fails at final step trying to install pip

Tags: macos, python-2.7, ssl, pip, pyenv

I'm trying to install python2.7 on my MacBook with OS Monterey 12.3.1 with the following command:

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include"
$ pyenv install 2.7.7
```

The installation of python2 seems to be coupled with the installation of pip. When pyenv is attempting to install pip the `pyenv install` command fails with the following output:

```
$ pyenv install 2.7.7
Downloading openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz...
-> https://pyenv.github.io/pythons/6b3977c61f2aedf0f96367dcfb5c6e578cf37e7b8d913b4ecb6643c3cb88d8c0
Installing openssl-1.0.2k...
Installed openssl-1.0.2k to ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7

python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-2.7.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.7/Python-2.7.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-2.7.7...
patching file ./Lib/site.py
patching file ./Lib/ssl.py
patching file ./Modules/_ssl.c
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py...
error: failed to install pip via get-pip.py

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/wr/zfs3tyhj67366bgn7ftymcs80000gn/T/python-build.20220422123040.23748
Results logged to /var/folders/wr/zfs3tyhj67366bgn7ftymcs80000gn/T/python-build.20220422123040.23748.log
```

Last 10 log lines:

```
WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org')), 'subject': ((('commonName', u'www.python.org'),),)}
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/pip/
/var/folders/wr/zfs3tyhj67366bgn7ftymcs80000gn/T/tmptKInSX/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org')), 'subject': ((('commonName', u'www.python.org'),),)}
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/pip/
/var/folders/wr/zfs3tyhj67366bgn7ftymcs80000gn/T/tmptKInSX/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org')), 'subject': ((('commonName', u'www.python.org'),),)}
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
```

It seems that everything is working but the root certificate of pypi.org isn't trusted which doesn't make sense because I can view the cert in my browser and it shows that it is trusted.

What am I failing to understand and how can I get pyenv to complete the installation of python2.7.7 and pip?

Comment: hey did you solve this issue? I have the same problem. Is it even possible to install python 2.7 with pyenv on monterey?